# Nested OneToMany mapping with 3 tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have 3 tables with below Schema:

> Table 1: KEY
> Primary Key: **KEY_ID**

> Table 2: KEY_VERSION:
> Primary Key: **KEY_ID** (Foreign key to KEY.KEY_ID) and **VERSION**

> Table 3: KEY_VERSION_BLOCK:
> Primary Key: **KEY_ID**, **VERSION** (Foreign key to KEY_VERSION.KEY_ID, KEY_VERSION.VERSION), **BLOCK_TYPE**

I am trying to establish this relationship using hibernate like below.

```
public class Key implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private KeyId keyId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Key", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<KeyVersion> keyVersions;
.....
}
```

```
// Embedded ID is not required here as it has only one key column, I will replace it, please ignore for now
@Embeddable
public class KeyId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "KEY_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long keyId;

}
```

```
public class KeyVersion implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private KeyVersionId versionId;

    @MapsId("KeyId")
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "KEY_ID") })
    @ManyToOne
    public Key key;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "KeyVersion", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<KeyVersionBlock> keyVersionBlocks;

.....
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class KeyVersionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Key key;

    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Integer version;

.....
}
```

```
public class KeyVersionBlock implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private KeyVersionBlockId keyVersionBlockId;

    @MapsId("keyVersionId")
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "KEY_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "VERSION") })
    @ManyToOne
    private KeyVersion keyVersion;

....
}
```

```
public class KeyVersionBlockId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "BLOCK_TYPE")
    private Long blockType;

    private KeyVersionId keyVersionId;

....
}
```

I am getting below error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
> referencedColumnNames(KEY_ID, VERSION) of
> com.akamai.portal.dexp.kms.core.model.KeyVersionBlock.keyVersion
> referencing com.akamai.portal.dexp.kms.core.model.KeyVersion not
> mapped to a single property   at
> org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:203)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:104)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]

Please help me getting rid of this error or establishing this relationship in some other way.

I also tried adding below in `KEY_VERSION` table, but that didn't help:

`@Column(name = "KEY_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false) private Long keyId;`

Comment: I don’t believe you can have reference mappings inside primary keys (in embeddedid). Your mapsId in keyVersion should refer to a basic mapping for KeyId. I’m not sure why you bother with an embededId for keyId when it is just a  wrapper for a lnog value

Comment: Yes, I can have basic mapping for keyId. But even with that how can I establish relationship between KeyVersion and keyVersionBlock?

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not allow relationships in the primary key itself. JPA 3.0 Section 11.1.17:

> Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not
> supported.

Derived ID does allow you to reference the key of a referenced class within the ID, so what you need instead is:

```
public class Key implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "KEY_ID", nullable = false)
  public Long keyId;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Key", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<KeyVersion> keyVersions;
.....
}

public class KeyVersion implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private KeyVersionId versionId;

  @MapsId("key")
  @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "KEY_ID") })
  @ManyToOne
  public Key key;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "KeyVersion", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<KeyVersionBlock> keyVersionBlocks;

.....
}

@Embeddable
public class KeyVersionId implements Serializable {
  //named this way as this could be used as an ID class instead of embeddable
  private Long key;

  @Column(name = "VERSION")
  private Integer version;

.....
}
```

What you have for the KeyVersionBlock and KeyVersionBlockId should then work since there are no longer any relationships in the key objects despite nesting of embeddables.